# Is there a way to do recurring sends of a transaction like a subscription model?

Tags: transactions, subscription

Is there an on chain way of doing recurring sends of a transaction to an address for a subscription model? Or do I need to tap into a 3rd party service to do the actual sending of the transactions and time keeping?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a 3rd party service.

I would recommend looking into [Cronos](https://solana.com/riptide/voting/cronos), they are the grand champion of the riptide Hackathon earlier this year.